# Merging two dataframes based on irregular time column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, time-series

I have two irregular times-series as dataframes (DataA and DataB) whose rows represent the value of a trait (A or B) of items at various times:

```
DataA                      DataB
time item_id  valueA       time   item_id  valueB
0    x        A1           3      x        B1
1    y        A2           4      y        B2
2    z        A3           5      x        B3
6    y        A4           6      y        B4
7    z        A5           7      z        B5
9    x        A6           8      x        B6
10   y        A7           10     y        B7
11   z        A8           11     z        B8
12   z        A9
```

DF definition in python:

```
dataA = [
    [0 , 'x', 'A1'], [1 , 'y', 'A2'], [2 , 'z', 'A3'],
    [6 , 'y', 'A4'], [7 , 'z', 'A5'], [9 , 'x', 'A6'],
    [10, 'y', 'A7'], [11, 'z', 'A8'], [12, 'z', 'A9']]

dataB = [
    [3 , 'x', 'B1'], [4 , 'y', 'B2'], [5 , 'x', 'B3'],
    [6 , 'y', 'B4'], [7 , 'z', 'B5'], [8 , 'x', 'B6'],
    [10, 'y', 'B7'], [11, 'z', 'B8']]

dataA_df = pd.DataFrame(dataA, columns = ['time', 'item_id', 'valueA'])
dataB_df = pd.DataFrame(dataB, columns = ['time', 'item_id', 'valueB'])
```

---

I would like to generate a single merged dataframe that would result in the following:

```
time  item_id   valueA   valueB
0     x         A1       NaN
1     y         A2       NaN
2     z         A3       NaN
3     x         A1       B1
4     y         A2       B2
5     x         A1       B3
6     y         A4       B4
7     z         A5       B5
8     x         A1       B6
9     x         A6       B6
10    y         A7       B7
11    z         A8       B8
12    z         A9       B8
```

Where:

1. If there is an item X which has an update at time T for both valueA and valueB that there be a row with both those values.
2. Otherwise if there is an item X which has an update for only one value (either valueA or valueB) that there be a row containing that value and for the other missing value to be the previous value
3. If there is no previous value for the missing value from [2], then NaN should be used in its place

Comment: how  is row 12 Value B -> B5??? there is a B8 right before..

Comment: @StevenG that was a typo - thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

start by merging your frames and ordering them:

```
df = pd.merge(
    left=dataA_df, 
    right=dataB_df, 
    on=['time', 'item_id'], 
    how='outer'
)
df = df.sort_values('time')
```

then forward fill by item_id

```
df.groupby('item_id').ffill()

time item_id valueA valueB
0       x     A1    NaN
1       y     A2    NaN
2       z     A3    NaN
3       x     A1     B1
4       y     A2     B2
5       x     A1     B3
6       y     A4     B4
7       z     A5     B5
8       x     A1     B6
9       x     A6     B6
10       y     A7     B7
11       z     A8     B8
12       z     A9     B8
```

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: `df.sort_values(['time', 'item_id'])`